# Set Timeout in Chrome debugger tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, settimeout, javascript-debugger

I try to run a script in the chrome debugger tools. Within the script I would like to wait (e.g. for a button after a rendered animation). How can I do this? I found some solutions like that:

```
async function test () {
    console.log('1');
    await setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('2');
    }, 3000);
    console.log('3');   
}
```

I expected to print 1, 2 and after three seconds 3. But the result is 1,3 and then 2 after three seconds.

I would like to do it for several sequential actions.

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot `await` the result of the `setTimeout` function because it is not a `Promise`. To do what you want to do, you could create a `Promise` that resolve after 3 seconds, here is an example:

```js
async function test() {
  console.log('1');
  console.log('2');
  await new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 3000);
  });
  console.log('3');
}

test();
```

From your description it seems like you want to access some DOM elements when they become available, there is [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) for that, here is an example:

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('#parent');

setTimeout(() => {
  const button = document.createElement('button');
  button.textContent = 'BUTTON';
  button.id = 'targetBtn';
  parent.appendChild(button);
}, 2000);

const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationList) => {
  mutationList.forEach((mutationRecord) => {
    if (mutationRecord.addedNodes && mutationRecord.addedNodes.length) {
      const btn = [...mutationRecord.addedNodes].find(n => n.matches && n.matches('#targetBtn'));
      if (btn) {
        console.log('Button #' + btn.id + ' was found');
      }
    }
  });
});
observer.observe(parent, {
  childList: true
});
```

```html
<div id="parent">
</div>
```

What this does is to monitor `#parent` element's child list to see when the `#targetBtn` element is added.

This is kind of overkill, a better solution will be to monitor events that will cause the targeted element to become available.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking two different questions. One asking how to wait for the element to be the DOM and another question about how asynchronous actions work in JavaScript.

For waiting for an element to be displayed the DOM, the simplest solution (in my opinion) would be to create a `while` loop and break once the element exists:

```js
// NOTE: this code isn't tested nor I have tried to see if it works

let elem = document.querySelector('.someSelector');

while(!elem) {
  elem = document.querySelector('.someSelector');
}

// do something else when the element shows
```

Keep in mind that this could cause memory leak issues.

> I expected to print 1, 2 and after three seconds 3.

Your expectation is wrong. The way `setTimeout` works is that it will add your callback function to a separate stack and call it after the amount of milliseconds you define. If you wanted to show three after 3 seconds you would have to do:

```js
function test() {
  console.log('1');
  console.log('2');
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('3');
  }, 3000);
}
```

Or using async/await

```js
async function test() {
  console.log('1');
  console.log('2');
  await new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 3000);
  });
  console.log('3');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, `await` waits for a promise to get resolved or rejected. `setTimeout` doesn’t return a Promise and hence the execution moves to the next line which outputs 3. 
Helpful read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

In terms of waiting for an element, it depends on what framework you are using. For plain JavaScript, you could trigger a custom event in addition to making the button visible. React has ways where you can trigger actions based on certain prop changes.